# Changing DB9 Gender: Crossover or Straight?

Tags: serial, rs232, db9

I have a USB-DB9(Male) that needs to communicate with a device that has a DB9(Male) port.

Do I connect both DB9(male) ports together using a null modem (crossover) cable or a straight through cable?

Pinout of device is [here](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/ur/pin651c.aspx). Pin 2 is Transmit, Pin 3 is Receive.

Pinout of USB-RS232 cable, I assume is the same pinout as the one found on computer motherboards. Pin 2 is TX, 3 is RX.

Comment: You have to get into the '90s approach to such problems.  Just keep stacking gender changers, 25's to 9's, 9's to 25's, and null modems until something works.  Then you use that forever, and never ever replace any adapters you may have used, so the next time you need them, you appreciate how valuable they are.

Comment: You have a 50% chance of getting it right first time. None of the things you read here will change that. Just suck it and see.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The important thing is to also wonder if you can somehow use a Centronics printer cable as well to get to your final desired connector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to be sure is to measure the voltage on pins 2 and 3 with a multimeter while the device is powered up, but otherwise idle. The pin that is functioning as an output (regardless of whether it is called "Transmit" or "Receive") will have a definite negative bias on it (anywhere from -5V to -12V typically), while the pin that is functioning as an input will be close to 0V.

Connect the input pin of the device to pin 2 of the PC (or USB to RS-232 adapter), and connect the output pin to pin 3.

---

After looking at Table 9 in the manual, I think that the description of the two cables strongly hints that the device is DCE, which means that you'll need a straight-through cable.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether the devices are ["DTE" or "DCE"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_circuit-terminating_equipment).

If they're both computers, you need a null modem. If one of them is a modem, or modem-like device, then you don't.

Comment: One is a computer, the other is this [device](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/R/651Cman.pdf). Can't figure out from the manual whether its a DTE or DCE.

Comment: Pinout of device is [here](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/ur/pin651c.aspx). Pin 2 is Transmit, Pin 3 is Receive.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Calling a pin "Transmit" or "Receive" is only half the story. The key question is whether the device considers "Transmit" to be an input (DCE) or an output (DTE).

Answer (score 0):

I would try without cross-over first, and if you don't get a response, try crossing tx and rx. RS-232 is often a case of trial-and-error.

I used to have a set of gender changers, cables and null-modems with me at all times, before USB...

Comment: .... and we liked it just fine!!